# Build 64 vs build 32 bit mode in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I am developing a web application that contains some features which do not work unless the application is built in 32 bit mode.

This limitation forces me to build the whole application in 32 bit mode, which produces some limitation on memory consumption of the application which is limited to 2 GB.

How can I find a solution for this problem?

Comment: What are the 32-bit features?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the 32-bit code and 64-bit code into two processes and communicate between the two.

You cannot load and execute 32-bit in a 64-bit process or vice versa.

Or, you can change the code that has memory constraints to use and process data differently.